# Printing out list of layers and associated information

Tags: qgis

Under Layer/Layer Properties/Information in the menu, there is a table named "Information from Provider" which gives information about the layer such as Name, Path, Geometry, CRS, etc. Is there a menu item somewhere or a plug-in that will print out a list of this information for all layers in a project?

I am using QGIS version LTR 3.10.4.

Answer (score 3):

Save the map as a QGIS project file, either as a QGS file or QGZ file (this one you have to unzip first). The QGS file has all the setting ordered in readable XML like:

```xml
 <projectCrs>
    <spatialrefsys>
      <wkt>PROJCRS["ETRS89 / UTM zone 32N",BASEGEOGCRS["ETRS89",DATUM["European Terrestrial Reference System 1989",ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],ID["EPSG",4258]],CONVERSION["UTM zone 32N",METHOD["Transverse Mercator",ID["EPSG",9807]],PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],ID["EPSG",8801]],PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",9,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],ID["EPSG",8802]],PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",0.9996,SCALEUNIT["unity",1],ID["EPSG",8805]],PARAMETER["False easting",500000,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],ID["EPSG",8806]],PARAMETER["False northing",0,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],ID["EPSG",8807]]],CS[Cartesian,2],AXIS["(E)",east,ORDER[1],LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],AXIS["(N)",north,ORDER[2],LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],USAGE[SCOPE["unknown"],AREA["Europe - 6°E to 12°E and ETRS89 by country"],BBOX[38.76,6,83.92,12]],ID["EPSG",25832]]</wkt>
      <proj4>+proj=utm +zone=32 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs</proj4>
      <srsid>2105</srsid>
      <srid>25832</srid>
      <authid>EPSG:25832</authid>
      <description>ETRS89 / UTM zone 32N</description>
      <projectionacronym>utm</projectionacronym>
      <ellipsoidacronym>EPSG:7019</ellipsoidacronym>
      <geographicflag>false</geographicflag>
    </spatialrefsys>
  </projectCrs>
```

...

```xml
<mapcanvas name="theMapCanvas" annotationsVisible="1">
    <units>meters</units>
    <extent>
      <xmin>430216.55700000002980232</xmin>
      <ymin>6040971.38950000051409006</ymin>
      <xmax>904309.74300000001676381</xmax>
      <ymax>6411075.410500000230968</ymax>
    </extent>
    <rotation>0</rotation>
    <destinationsrs>
      <spatialrefsys>
        <wkt>PROJCRS["ETRS89 / UTM zone 32N",BASEGEOGCRS["ETRS89",DATUM["European Terrestrial Reference System 1989",ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],ID["EPSG",4258]],CONVERSION["UTM zone 32N",METHOD["Transverse Mercator",ID["EPSG",9807]],PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],ID["EPSG",8801]],PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",9,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],ID["EPSG",8802]],PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",0.9996,SCALEUNIT["unity",1],ID["EPSG",8805]],PARAMETER["False easting",500000,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],ID["EPSG",8806]],PARAMETER["False northing",0,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],ID["EPSG",8807]]],CS[Cartesian,2],AXIS["(E)",east,ORDER[1],LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],AXIS["(N)",north,ORDER[2],LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],USAGE[SCOPE["unknown"],AREA["Europe - 6°E to 12°E and ETRS89 by country"],BBOX[38.76,6,83.92,12]],ID["EPSG",25832]]</wkt>
        <proj4>+proj=utm +zone=32 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs</proj4>
        <srsid>2105</srsid>
        <srid>25832</srid>
        <authid>EPSG:25832</authid>
        <description>ETRS89 / UTM zone 32N</description>
        <projectionacronym>utm</projectionacronym>
        <ellipsoidacronym>EPSG:7019</ellipsoidacronym>
        <geographicflag>false</geographicflag>
      </spatialrefsys>
    </destinationsrs>
    <rendermaptile>0</rendermaptile>
    <expressionContextScope/>
  </mapcanvas>
```

...

```xml
<projectlayers>
    <maplayer simplifyMaxScale="1" geometry="Polygon" simplifyDrawingHints="1" wkbType="MultiPolygon" autoRefreshTime="0" simplifyLocal="1" styleCategories="AllStyleCategories" labelsEnabled="1" minScale="100000000" refreshOnNotifyEnabled="0" type="vector" hasScaleBasedVisibilityFlag="0" autoRefreshEnabled="0" readOnly="0" simplifyAlgorithm="0" maxScale="0" refreshOnNotifyMessage="" simplifyDrawingTol="1">
      <extent>
        <xmin>441504.48999999999068677</xmin>
        <ymin>6049783.38999999966472387</ymin>
        <xmax>893021.81000000005587935</xmax>
        <ymax>6402263.41000000014901161</ymax>
      </extent>
      <id>kommunegraense_2010a966_28c3_4cbe_8d34_07245e57b051</id>
      <datasource>dbname='grukos' host=10.33.131.50 port=5432 user='xxx' password='xxx' sslmode=disable key='id' srid=25832 type=MultiPolygon checkPrimaryKeyUnicity='1' table="kort"."kommunegraense" (geom)</datasource>
      <keywordList>
        <value></value>
      </keywordList>
      <layername>kommunegraense</layername>
      <srs>
        <spatialrefsys>
          <wkt>PROJCRS["ETRS89 / UTM zone 32N",BASEGEOGCRS["ETRS89",DATUM["European Terrestrial Reference System 1989",ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],ID["EPSG",4258]],CONVERSION["UTM zone 32N",METHOD["Transverse Mercator",ID["EPSG",9807]],PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],ID["EPSG",8801]],PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",9,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],ID["EPSG",8802]],PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",0.9996,SCALEUNIT["unity",1],ID["EPSG",8805]],PARAMETER["False easting",500000,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],ID["EPSG",8806]],PARAMETER["False northing",0,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],ID["EPSG",8807]]],CS[Cartesian,2],AXIS["(E)",east,ORDER[1],LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],AXIS["(N)",north,ORDER[2],LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],USAGE[SCOPE["unknown"],AREA["Europe - 6°E to 12°E and ETRS89 by country"],BBOX[38.76,6,83.92,12]],ID["EPSG",25832]]</wkt>
          <proj4>+proj=utm +zone=32 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs</proj4>
          <srsid>2105</srsid>
          <srid>25832</srid>
          <authid>EPSG:25832</authid>
          <description>ETRS89 / UTM zone 32N</description>
          <projectionacronym>utm</projectionacronym>
          <ellipsoidacronym>EPSG:7019</ellipsoidacronym>
          <geographicflag>false</geographicflag>
        </spatialrefsys>
      </srs>
      <resourceMetadata>
        <identifier></identifier>
        <parentidentifier></parentidentifier>
        <language></language>
        <type></type>
        <title></title>
        <abstract></abstract>
        <links/>
        <fees></fees>
        <encoding></encoding>
        <crs>
          <spatialrefsys>
            <wkt></wkt>
            <proj4></proj4>
            <srsid>0</srsid>
            <srid>0</srid>
            <authid></authid>
            <description></description>
            <projectionacronym></projectionacronym>
            <ellipsoidacronym></ellipsoidacronym>
            <geographicflag>false</geographicflag>
          </spatialrefsys>
        </crs>
        <extent/>
```

You could write some XSLT converting chosen XML to HTML https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_transformation.asp